# How do I fix an error on my terminal when running the command npm start

Tags: terminal, owasp

I get this error when trying to to run command npm:

> juice-shop@9.3.1 start
> node app

info: All dependencies in ./package.json are satisfied (OK)
node: symbol lookup error: /home/kali/Downloads/juice-shop_9.3.1/node_modules/libxmljs2/build/Release/xmljs.node: undefined symbol: _ZN2v87Isolate19CheckMemoryPressureEv

My node version: v18.13.0
My npm version: 9.2.0
My OWASP juice shop version: 9.3.1

I am expecting to open the OWASP juice shop in my browser

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the juice-shop-14.5.1_node18_linux_x64.tgz from v14.5.1 directory from Source Forge. It is probably happening due to incompatibility between the latest juice shop version and nodeJS version. It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue by using nodejs version 12, try this out:

First you have to install nvm

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash
```

note: after installation finished close your teminal and open a new one

After that, install nodejs version 12 using nvm

```
nvm install 12
```

note: this installation will using npm v6.14.16

Now you can run npm inside your juice-shop_9.3.1 directory

```
npm start
```

Good luck ;)